# Make docker build --memory-swap=20g use the available swap space?

Tags: docker, swap, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have run `free -h` and see that I have 29G of swap space.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        6.9G        8.8G         17M        223M        8.9G
Swap:           29G        2.0M         29G
```

I have also enabled 100 swappiness.

```
$ sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=100
vm.swappiness = 100
$ cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
100
```

However, `docker build --memory-swap=20g` does not appear to use the swap space. This is the output of `htop` throughout the docker build.

```
1  [||||||||||||||||                                                           18.7%] 
2  [|||||||                                                                     7.3%] 
3  [||||||||||||||||||||||                                                     26.5%] 
4  [|||||||||||||||                                                            18.0%] 
Mem[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                                  6.47G/15.9G] 
Swp[|                                                                    2.00M/29.6G]
```

This is the docker build command:

```
docker build --build-arg NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=325" \ 
             --memory=600m --memory-swap=20g \
             --cpu-period=100000 --cpu-quota=50000 \
             --no-cache --tag farm_app_image:latest --file Dockerfile .
```

The docker build appears to be running out of RAM, because the build's internal process (NodeJS) runs out of heap space and crashes. Also, immediately before the crash the memory is maxed:

```
shaun@DESKTOP-5T629JB:/mnt/c/Users/bigfo$ docker ps -q | xargs  docker stats --no-stream
CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
66bdf8efb492        charming_maxwell    51.72%              562.2MiB / 600MiB   93.70%              46.8MB / 1.53MB     277MB / 230MB       94
```

Why is it running out of RAM without using the swap space? How can we make it use the available swap space?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm having the same

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try to run it with `--privileged` flag.

```
docker run -ti --privileged yourimage
```

But make sure that you know what you are doing.

You should also read [docker-tips-privilaged-flag](https://medium.com/lucjuggery/docker-tips-mind-the-privileged-flag-d6e2ae71bdb4)